# Declaring new numeric types

Tags: c++

Back in university when i used pascal, i learnt that you could declare a type which was a range of numbers. It was something like:

```
<somekeyword> TypeName 1..10; or something like that.
```

Long story short, i was wondering if and how you can create a type that has a range of a possible number values.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT:
Sorry if i wasnt clear, i am looking for something in c++ in which i can declare a numeric type (eg byte (0..255) or DayOfYear (1..31)).

Comment: it was my poor memory of what you had to write in pascal. i dont know exactly what it looks like in either language but i hope it gets the message accross.

Comment: So what exactly do you want? An array of values from N to M? It isn't exactly clear to me.

Comment: An integer that allows values within the specified range. Pascal had that, but C++ doesn't.

Comment: The only possible thing I can think of would be done using templates, but it doesn't seem worth it.

Comment: Question edited to clarify.

Comment: Boost has a helper macro thingy.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf a 'helper macro thingy'? When in doubt, though, boost has *everything*.

Comment: @dick: i didn't find it again with quick google search, but the OP can invest the time.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf Ok, [Sadface] i was hoping it would be in compiler. maybe ill make some smart code for it. 

thanks all

Answer (score 0):

Something like this probably:

```
class range {
  int _start;
  int _end;
public:
  range(int s, int e): _start(s), _end(e) {}

  bool operator && (int n) const { return n >= _start && n <= _end; }

};
```

that you can use as:

```
range r(10,28);

if( r && 13 ) ... ;
else ... ;
```

Or simply as

```
if( range(12,34) && 13 ) ... ;
else ... ;
```

Comment: Yeah i was thinking of doing some smart class. But ill probably just leave it to case-specific validation. I mean, if the person wants to be born on the 36th of may, who am i to stop him?